# python 2.7 asynchronous function with tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to call a function asynchronously whilst using tkinter for a GUI. I am trying to run a print command that will run asynchronously to the GUI without freezing it and repeating it every 0.5 seconds. I don't understand how to do this from the tutorials I've looked at and would love to get some help. Here is the condensed code as an example to explain the problem I'm having. I am also using python 2.7 in case that makes a difference.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class TestClass(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.create_view()

    def create_view(self):
        self.labelTitle = tk.Label(self, text="Live Camera Page",)
        self.labelTitle.pack()

    def asynchronous_function(self):
        print("I would like this to repeat every 0.5 seconds ...")

app = TestClass()
app.geometry("800x600")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Look into Tkinter's ``after`` method.

Comment: Have you tried creating a separate thread?

Comment: I have tried creating a seperate thread but I couldn't get it to work within tkinter. That's the problem I'm having really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function you want to run only takes a couple hundred milliseconds or less to run, you can use tkinter's `after` method. If it takes longer than that, you'll have to put this asynchronous function in another thread or in another process.

Comment: Well I plan on taking a picture every 0.5 seconds with simplecv and to put it onto a canvas on the tkinter GUI.

Comment: I will try using the after method and see if it's fast enough to use and go from there. Ill update the post with an answer once I have it working.